# how to sort dictionary based on another array

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, sorting

I have an array like this :

```
var orderToFollow:[String] = ["fromAccount", "toAccount", "amount", "benName"]
```

and a dictionary like this :

```
var randomOrderDic = [
      "benName": "abc", 
      "amount": 15.0, 
      "toAccount": "123456", 
      "fromAccount": "789530"
     ]
```

How can i sort the randomOrderDic to something like:

```
[
  "fromAccount": "789530", 
  "toAccount": "123456", 
  "amount": 15.0, 
  "benName": "abc"
]
```

P.S. I'm new to coding so i don't know how to solve this. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Dictionary is an unordered collection.  It doesn’t have any concept of being ordered so you can’t sort it like this (or rather… sorting it like this has no meaning). If you want to display the values in order you could loop through your array and use that to pull the values out of the dictionary.

Comment: so there's no way to have a dictionary with a specific key orders ?

Comment: no, there is no way to have a dictionary with a specific key order. See: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/collectiontypes/#Dictionaries

Comment: Why do you want to sort the dictionary?  If you want to access the keys in a specific order, you can use your array of keys to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are unordered by design. If you want to retrieve values in a certain order, you can iterate through an array of the keys in the order you want and retrieve each value.

```
for key in orderToFollow
{
    if let value = randomOrderDic[key]
    {
        // Do something with the value here
    }
}
```

That won't get you any of the keys that do not appear in `orderToFollow` of course. To get those, you can use a filter

```
let unorderedKeys = randomOrderDic.keys.filter { !orderToFollw.contains($0) }
```

Apple's [Swift collections package](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md) does offer an `OrderedDictionary` type, but it is probably better to get used to the fact that dictionary keys are unordered. There aren't may use-cases where you do need an ordering.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dictionary = [ "benName": "abc","amount": 15.0,"toAccount": "123456","fromAccount": "789530"] as [String : Any]

let array = ["fromAccount", "toAccount", "amount", "benName"]

let sortedDictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: dictionary.sorted { (first, second) -> Bool in
let index1 = array.firstIndex(of: first.key) ?? 0
let index2 = array.firstIndex(of: second.key) ?? 0
return index1 < index2
```

})

```
print(sortedDictionary)
```

//OutPut

```
["toAccount": "123456", "benName": "abc", "fromAccount": "789530", "amount": 15.0]
```

Comment: The *//OutPut* is an **array** of tuples, not a dictionary.

Comment: @vadian Updated it. we can use uniqueKeysWithValues.

Comment: Yes, but it’s still unordered. That’s the nature of a dictionary.

Comment: @vadian yeah :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sortedDic: [String: Any] = [:]

for key in orderToFollow {
    if let value = randomOrderDic[key] {
        sortedDic[key] = value
        randomOrderDic.removeValue(forKey: key)
    }
}

// Append any remaining keys in randomOrderDic to sortedDic
for (key, value) in randomOrderDic {
    sortedDic[key] = value
}
```

**This solution has a time complexity of O(n)**